# Return a variable value and output from PL/SQL code block to C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, plsql

I have a code block and I am assigning values to a variable to keep track what is going on while execution of the block.

```
begin 
 declare 
   stage number := 0; 
   begin
    stage := 1;
    INSERT INTO Country ( code, name) VALUES (1 , 'xxxx');
    stage := 2;
    INSERT INTO City ( code, name) VALUES (1 , 'yyyy');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE:'); 
COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occured, rollback...');  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.get_LINE(:1, :2);
   stage := -1;
   ROLLBACK; 
  end;
end;
```

I want to ask you how can I get stage value and the value inside DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() using C#. I know that this has been already answered but unfortunately I failed finding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
    OracleParameter status = new OracleParameter(":1", OracleType.VarChar, 32000);
    p_line.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    OracleParameter line = new OracleParameter(":2", OracleType.Double);
    p_status.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    OracleParameter stage= new OracleParameter("stage", OracleType.Int16);
    p_country_name.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;    

    cmd.CommandText = script;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(status);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(line );
    cmd.Parameters.Add(stage);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string status = status.Value.ToString();
    string line = line.Value.ToString();
    string stage= stage.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me for the stage variable, I had to use the following trick: SELECT stage into :stage FROM dual;

Answer (score 1):

I doubt C# will be able to read dbms_output buffer.

You can however write a stored plsql procedure for this code, and pass out parameter from that procedure to C#

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it is not my question. I asked how I can read "stage" variable and DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() in C# code.

Answer (score 1):

You can read from DBMS_OUTPUT!
That might be useful for asynchronous communication

```
FUNCTION get_next_line RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS
return_value VARCHAR2(255);
get_status INTEGER;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE (return_value, get_status);
IF get_status = 0
THEN
  RETURN return_value;
ELSE
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END;
```

But I would not recommend it to use in general case. You need an output parameter or function like example above.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it is not my question. I asked how I can read "stage" variable and DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() in C# code.

Comment: function is an example how to return stage variable. Don't read dbms_output.put_line in your code, use out parameters.

Answer (score -1):

i am new in c#. Want to write pl block query and get value.

```
StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(" declare ");
sp.Append(" v_acid   varchar(10);");
sp.Append(" v_Cid    varchar(10);");
sp.Append(" begin ");
sp.Append(" select acid,cust into v_acid,v_Cid from account where       account='112111' ");
sp.Append(" end ");
```

I want to run pl block written in above stringbuilder in oracle connection.